# For para criação de campos

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando fazer com que quando o usuário inserir determinado número em um `<input>` seja criado a mesma quantidade de campos, tentei fazer de uma maneira que encontrei aqui, mas não consegui fazer com que criasse o número de campos que digito, só cria um label, nem o input aparece, segue abaixo o código:

```
<div class="form-group" id="vem">
</div>
<input type="number" class="form-control round-input" name="numero_parc" required="required" min="1" id="par">

$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; 
  var wrapper = $("#vem"); 
  var add_button = $("#par");

  $(add_button).change(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  var length = wrapper.find("input:text#textAdded").length;

  $(wrapper).append('<label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">' + (length+1) +'</label><div class="col-md-5"><input type="date" class="form-control round-input" id="textAdded" name="num' + (length+1) + '"></div>');
  });
});
```

for:

```
function criaCampos(){
            var qtd = document.getElementById('par').value;            
            if (qtd > 1) {
              for(var i=0; i < qtd; i++){
                document.getElementById('vem').innerHTML = '<label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">1º</label><div class="col-md-5"><input type="date" class="form-control round-input" name="'+ qtd[i]+'"></div>';
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: Você esqueceu de fechar a div que contém o input

Comment: Mesmo assim não funciona

Comment: Sim, tem outros problemas. Falta o loop em si

Comment: Tenta apenas add_button.change(function(){ ... });

Comment: Isso, não sei como montar esse loop, ou se tivesse como através desse código criar o número de campos que o usuário escolher.

Comment: Pro loop você pode usar o "for". Dá uma lida: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: Eu tentei fazer um for da maneira que inseri na pergunta agora, mas não funcionou. Então achei esse segundo código, que pareceu melhor, mas ainda assim não funciona como preciso

Comment: `document.getElementById('vem').innerHTML += ...`

Comment: O que está dando errado é quando por exemplo, digito 3 para o nro de campos, mas aí o for cria dois e pára, e ainda o segundo é criado só o label, sem input

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ht6qgd83/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentei criar um exemplo para você de como pode ser feito. Utilizei `jQuery`, tudo bem?

No HTML deixei bem simples:

```
<input type="number" id="quantidade" value="0" />

<div id="campos">
</div>
```

E aqui o código `jQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#quantidade').on('change', function(){

      var quantidade = $('#quantidade').val(),
          campos = $('#campos');

      campos.html(''); //aqui eu fiz limpar a div
      for (x = 0; x < quantidade; x++) {
        campos.append('<input type="text" id="campo-'+x+'" />');
      }

    });

});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bxa85Lwq/)

Comment: Obrigada, ajustei algumas coisas de acordo com o que preciso e funcionou perfeitamente!